# Homogeneous hole pattern in the surface of a geodesic dome

Tags: modeling, faces, bevel, extrude

So, I am still fighting with the porous spheres.
I managed to create the holes in every single face of the icosahedral sphere (geodesic dome), however when doing the inset faces (I) and extruding inside, I should see a similar pattern of hexagon holes...instead of that, I observed also irregular pentagons and other weird figures.
I understand that in order to complete de perfect sphere, pentagons play an important role (like a soccer ball), but is there any way I could have exactly a similar pattern of holes?

This is the sequence of commands I conducted:

1. Added geodesic dome
   [image]

2)Inset FAces (I)
[image]

[image]

3)Extrude (E)
[image]

4)Bevel
[image]

Any idea?
Thanks

**Edited**: I would like to have something like that. No matter whether using hexagons, pentagons or whatever

[image]

Comment: I know that. I edited the question so that it can be understood correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I should have made this an extension to the original answer.. but here goes.

Activate the shipped add-on *Loop Tools*

After making the <kbd>I</kbd> Inset > Individual, use *Loop Tools > Circle* on all the selected faces, with a 'Radius' set. It's wise to estimate the desired radius before invoking, in this case; the operator is Python, and can be a bit sluggish.

[image]

The result will be slightly irregularly distributed holes, (as you noted, you can't tessellate a sphere with hexagons), but they will all be the same size.

Or.. you can <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd> select out the pentagons, and make those holes slightly smaller..

Or... you could use the same *Loop Tools* adjustment, on a different topology.

Comment: Great!. You're the best